# Option+Accent keys for accented characters on windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

I am used to an English international keyboard layout, and I work with Windows, Mac and Linux. Unfortunately, I'm also french so I need to be able to write with accents.

I like the way Mac does this:

- alt+` then e => è
- alt+e then e => é
- etc...

It's a bit arbitrary but it's pretty fast, non-obtrusive and I'm used to it.

I'm not looking to learn how to type accents in windows: I know how to do that. It's just kinda infuriating to have to switch from one way of writing to another when I switch OSes.

None of the tweaks I've found have been useful. One of them is almost OK, but it doesn't use a modifier key, meaning every time I want to type an apostrophe or other "special" characters (`"'~^`, etc...), it's considered a dead key and I have to remember to hit the space key after it.

Is there a way to imitate the MacOS behaviour on Windows ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Windows has a few ways of doing it. Depending on what works best for you, consider one of them, but it may not be perfect.

## Switching keyboard languages

This is in my humble opinion the best way to do it.

Add 2 keyboard languages. English - United states, French - United States International.

This will place the language switcher in your system tray and by holding left alt, followed by pressing shift once, you can switch between languages, turning the ~n and 'o into ñ and ó etc. After you switch to English, the annoyance of having to type a space to get " is gone.

With the language set to french, you can also use the right alt with letters etc to quickly create certain symbols, such as alt-gr+w = å, alt-gr+r = ® alt-gr+5 = €, etc.

## Learn the alt codes

All the special keys that one can press have an alt-code attached to it.
The list is here:

0156    9C  œ
0159    9F  Ÿ
0161    A1  ¡
0162    A2  ¢
0163    A3  £
0164    A4  ¤
0165    A5  ¥
0166    A6  ¦
0167    A7  §
0168    A8  ¨
0169    A9  ©
0170    AA  ª
0171    AB  «
0172    AC  ¬
0173    AD  ­
0174    AE  ®
0175    AF  ¯
0176    B0  °
0177    B1  ±
0178    B2  ²
0179    B3  ³
0180    B4  ´
0181    B5  µ
0182    B6  ¶
0183    B7  ·
0184    B8  ¸
0185    B9  ¹
0186    BA  º
0187    BB  »
0188    BC  ¼
0189    BD  ½
0190    BE  ¾
0191    BF  ¿
0192    C0  À
0193    C1  Á
0194    C2  Â
0195    C3  Ã
0196    C4  Ä
0197    C5  Å
0198    C6  Æ
0199    C7  Ç
0200    C8  È
0201    C9  É
0202    CA  Ê
0203    CB  Ë
0204    CC  Ì
0205    CD  Í
0206    CE  Î
0207    CF  Ï
0208    D0  Ð
0209    D1  Ñ
0210    D2  Ò
0211    D3  Ó
0212    D4  Ô
0213    D5  Õ
0214    D6  Ö
0215    D7  ×
0216    D8  Ø
0217    D9  Ù
0218    DA  Ú
0219    DB  Û
0220    DC  Ü
0221    DD  Ý
0222    DE  Þ
0223    DF  ß
0224    E0  à
0225    E1  á
0226    E2  â
0227    E3  ã
0228    E4  ä
0229    E5  å
0230    E6  æ
0231    E7  ç
0232    E8  è
0233    E9  é
0234    EA  ê
0235    EB  ë
0236    EC  ì
0237    ED  í
0238    EE  î
0239    EF  ï
0240    F0  ð
0241    F1  ñ
0242    F2  ò
0243    F3  ó
0244    F4  ô
0245    F5  õ
0246    F6  ö
0247    F7  ÷
0248    F8  ø
0249    F9  ù
0250    FA  ú
0251    FB  û
0252    FC  ü
0253    FD  ý
0254    FE  þ
0255    FF  ÿ

Hold left alt and then type the 4 digit code on the numpad, then release alt to get that character. You will likely only be using a few, so memorizing them should not be too hard.

## Use Insert Symbol

Some programs, such as Microsoft Word, allow you to insert these characters by inserting a symbol.

See this screenshot (sorry, my word is dutch)

[image]
[image]

Doubleclick a letter to insert it.